# How to get WIndows Vista to remember the Option Size All Colums To Fit for all Folders

Tags: windows-vista

How to get WIndows Vista to remember the Option Size All Colums To Fit for all Folders everytime.

Rightclick on name and you would see the option Size All Colums Ti Fit. How do i get Vista to remember this option for all folders? Currently when i activate it, and i go to another folder it doesn't apply for that folder nor when i close the current folder in which i have applied said option and then open the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if *Apply to All Folders* will work?

I'm not sure how you get to Folder Options in Vista, but here is the window:

[image]